# Can we use PostgREST API with Azure

Tags: azure, postgrest

I am working with PostgreSQL which is present in Azure. I want to **implement API for PostgreSQL database with PostgREST API**. Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not using azure postgresql db rest api to manage your cloud database?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/postgresql/

Comment: Ya we can use. But i want to use PostgREST API. But i cant find much resources on it. Thanks @JayGong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any direct evidences to prove your requirement from [official document](https://postgrest.org/en/v6.0/tutorials/tut0.html) indeed as same as you, however I try to ask some experiences from this [chat room](https://gitter.im/begriffs/postgrest).

[image]

It seems that someone else connects with Google Cloud PostgreSQL database successfully.

[image]

So I would suggest you trying to follow the [tutorial](http://postgrest.org/en/v6.0/tutorials/tut0.html#step-5-run-postgrest) to plug the correct credentials with Azure PostgreSQL db.

[image]

Comment: @RevanthOleti You're so kind. If you think it's beneficial, would you please accept it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ya sure @JayGong